# How to install Big Sur Beta on Parallels

Tags: macos, mac, parallels

How can I install the new Mac OS Big Sur Beta on Parallels?

I don't want to upgrade my existing Catalina until the official release of Big Sur arrives, but for testing of my apps I need Big Sur.

I know that to install Big Sur, we need to download the Upgrade OS from Apple. But I am not sure, how that will install in Parallels?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Tetsujin: I am out of idea, as how can I download entire big sur (image, iso etc) and install it in Parallels. What I know is for big sur we need to get the upgrade tool, which runs and upgrades current OS to Big Sur.

Comment: I've not tried with Big Sure, but the usual trick is to install the current OS, then enrol it in the program & run the beta as an upgrade from the Software Update CP.